# Fatal Exception on 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference'

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I have been following a tutorial for adding a card-like swipe views using a view pager shown here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsXv6VRqZKs

I have tried to make it work with fragments, however I have run into this error:

```
2020-02-22 16:04:41.218 9582-9582/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.musicassistant, PID: 9582
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.musicassistant.CardsFragment.onCreateView(CardsFragment.java:38)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Here is my code:

```
fragment_cards.xml
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    >

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"></androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_shuffle"
        android:text="SHUFFLE"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewPager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/viewPager"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/viewPager">

    </Button>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
CardsFragment.java
```

```
package com.example.musicassistant;

import android.animation.ArgbEvaluator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class CardsFragment extends Fragment {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    Adapter adapter;
    List<Model> models;
    Integer[] colors = null;
    ArgbEvaluator argbEvaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        models = new ArrayList<>();
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.brochure, "Brochure", "oooooo"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.sticker, "Sticker", "oooooo"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.poster, "Poster", "oooooo"));
        models.add(new Model(R.drawable.namecard, "Namecard", "oooooo"));

        adapter = new Adapter(models, getActivity());

        viewPager = fragment_cards.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPadding(130,0,130,0);

        Integer[] colors_temp = {
                getResources().getColor(R.color.color1),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.color2),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.color3),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.color4)

        };

        colors = colors_temp;

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (position < (adapter.getCount() -1) && position < (colors.length -1)) {
                    viewPager.setBackgroundColor(
                            (Integer) argbEvaluator.evaluate(
                                    positionOffset,
                                    colors[position],
                                    colors[position + 1]
                            )
                    );
                } else {
                    viewPager.setBackgroundColor(colors[colors.length - 1]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards, container, false);
    }
}
```

```
Adapter.java
```

```
package com.example.musicassistant;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private List<Model> models;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Model> models, FragmentActivity context) {
        this.models = models;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title, desc;

        imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        desc = view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        imageView.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImage());
        title.setText(models.get(position).getTitle());
        desc.setText(models.get(position).getDesc());

        container.addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

```
Model.java
```

```
package com.example.musicassistant;

public class Model {

    private int image;
    private String title;
    private  String desc;

    public Model(int image, String title, String desc) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to programming in Android Studio and any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time,

Roman

Comment: You haven't initialised the "fragments_card"  in your CardsFragments.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `CardsFragment#onCreateView`, you are trying `viewPager = fragment_cards.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);` which is throwing this exception as the `fragment_cards` is not initiated at that point of time.

You can try following in `CardsFragment#onCreateView` to avoid the issue:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...

        fragment_cards = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards, container, false);
        viewPager = fragment_cards.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ...
        return fragment_cards; 
    }
```

In the above code, we are inflating the layout file and storing the root view's reference in `fragment_cards` allowing you to find all the views present in the layout  file by using `findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

View rootView = inflater​.​inflate​(​R​.​layout​.​fragment_top_rated​, container,         false);
Viewpager=rootview.findviewbyid(R.id.viewpager)
        return rootView;